# CSS/Bootstrap3 - Why do column classes have a 'min-height' value?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Does anybody know the purpose for Boostrap col-**-* classes having a minimum height value declaration? and why just one pixel?

**Boostrap column class CSS:**

```
position: relative;
min-height: 1px; <--- ??
padding-right: 15px;
padding-left: 15px;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Bootstrap's [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) on the grid system:

> ```
>  // Prevent columns from collapsing when empty
>  min-height: 1px;
> ```

Columns will collapse horizontally if they contain no content. So, adding a `min-height` of `1px` allows you to create empty columns that still render and affect the page layout without putting anything in them. `1px` is just the smallest size possible to do so with.

Comment: That makes sense. I only noticed it because i was toggling the visibility of elements inside certain column classes and as a result i notice there was a 1px of space remaining once the content was hidden. A simple attribute selector solved that problem for me. I just wanted to make sure i understood what was going on before removing it.